# Data migration using blobstore API fails

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am migrating files from S3 to GCS using Blobstore API. I created the south data migration script to update metadata for the files:

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import images

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
    images = orm['core.Image'].objects.all()
    for image in images:
        blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs/mybucket/' + image.name)
        try:
            url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
        except images.ObjectNotFoundError:
            url = ''
        image.url = url
        image.save()
...
```

When I try to run the script inside the AppEngine project:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 485, in create_gs_key
    rpc = create_gs_key_async(filename, rpc)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 525, in create_gs_key_async
    lambda rpc: rpc.response.blob_key())
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 226, in _make_async_call
    rpc = create_rpc()
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 220, in create_rpc
    return apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC('blobstore', deadline, callback)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 413, in __init__
    self.__rpc = CreateRPC(service, stubmap)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 67, in CreateRPC
    assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "blobstore"
```

I see that the `manage.py` doesn't take advantage of AppEngine dev server bootstraping and authentication. Anyone knows how to resolve the issue? How to use AppEngine dev tools from `manage.py`.

I looked up [django-rocket-engine](http://django-rocket-engine.readthedocs.org/) project which uses similar idea but it's quite old and is not supported. Some of the APIs have been deprecated by Google.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the solution I would consider optimal but it does the trick. I used AppEngine Remote API to use blobstore along with Django models. You need first to modify `app.yaml` script:

```
# app.yaml
handlers:
- url: /remoteapi.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
  login: admin
```

and then use the `remote_api_shell.py` script to access the shell. You can use the script to access both local dev_appserver and remote appengine. For local dev_appserver just use `-s localhost:8080`. Make sure that `DATABASES` in `settings.py` is setup properly pointing to the right database.

Here is the session which uses Remote API shell:

```
$GAE_SDK_ROOT/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py -s APP-ID.appspot.com
Email: <admin-email>
Password: 
App Engine remote_api shell
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:39:55) 
[GCC 4.8.1]
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
s~APP-ID> import os, sys
s~APP-ID> sys.path.insert(0, os.environ['GAE_SDK_ROOT'] + '/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5')
s~APP-ID> import django
s~APP-ID> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 4, 'final', 0)
s~APP-ID> sys.path.append('/home/user/myproject/myproject')
s~APP-ID> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
'settings'
s~APP-ID> from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
s~APP-ID> from google.appengine.api import images
s~APP-ID> from myproject.core.models import Image
s~APP-ID> images = Image.objects.all()
s~APP-ID> for image in images:
...     blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs/mybucket/' + image.name)
...     try:
...         url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
...     except images.ObjectNotFoundError:
...         url = ''
...     image.url = url
...     image.save()
```